# setImageBias is not working on a LAMP box

Tags: php, imagick

I have this code:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '__stack__.jpg');

$image->medianFilterImage(2);
$image->setColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$image->medianFilterImage(2);
$xKernel = array(-0.70,0,0.70,-0.70,0,0.70,-0.70,0,0.70);
$max = $image->getQuantumRange();
$max = $max["quantumRangeLong"];
$image->setImageBias(0.50 * $max); // -bias 50%
$image->convolveImage($xKernel, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
```

Which I'm running under a WAMP box and under a LAMP box. Local/Production, respectively.
Both are running imagick 3.1.2.
LAMP's imagemagick version is: ImageMagick 6.8.8-7 Q16 x86_64
WAMP's imagemagick version is: ImageMagick 6.7.7-0 Q16
**LAMP** box won't run setImageBias properly and ends up with this result:
[image: LAMPs result]
WAMP box gives the intended result though:
[image: WAMPs result]

I couldn't find any information about setImageBias() being buggy nor any change about `-bias` on imagemagick's changelog between those versions.
I think I'm doing it the proper way - calling it before convolving an image - but I don't know why this isn't working on my LAMP box.

`__stack__.jpg`:
[image: __stack__.jpg]

Comment: It looks like setImageBias might be borked. It just doesn't seem to work on the latest version of ImageMagick, maybe raise an issue on https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ ? btw you probably mean transformImageColorSpace rather than setColorSpace

Comment: You're right about the colorspace, thank you. Also, I've opened an issue on imagick's github.

Comment: Should I add the imagemagick tag? As I suspect this isn't entirely imagick's fault.