# Determine max possible intensity of image

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Starting to use the PHP Imagick classes and the lack of documentation. In particular using the [paintTransparentImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.painttransparentimage.php) method.

In the CLI version of ImageMagick one can simply pass a percentage for the `fuzz` parameter. However, in PHP it seems you have to specify it as an amount relative to the ["maximum possible intensity"](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz) of the image.

How do you determine the max possible intensity of an image then? Apparently it can be 255, 65535, or 4294967295.

Comment: I am not sure for PHP, but I think it depends on the `quantisation` at which you have installed ImageMagick, if it is 8, then 255, if 16 then 65535 and if 32 then 4 billion. You can see if you do `identify | grep -i version` and look for the `Q` factor.

Comment: Or you can use `convert xc: -format "%[fx:quantumrange]" info:`

Comment: @MarkSetchell is correct. Use [Imagick::getQuantumDepth](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getquantumdepth.php) to determine the Q factor.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for this info. I'm trying to get the code all in PHP Imagick now and not hit the shell at all. A lofty goal I know as the docs are sparse for PHP Imagick, but I think as I use it more and become familiar w/ the library it is possible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PHP you would determine the quantum range, and calculate the intensity with `pow(2,Q)`

```php
$img = new Imagick('source.png');
$quantum = $img->getQuantumDepth()['quantumDepthLong'];
$target = 'black';
$alpha = 0.0; // Fully transparent
$fuzz = 0.5 * pow(2,$quantum); // From black to gray50
$img->paintTransparentImage($target, $alpha, $fuzz);
```

From the above comments, the maximum intensity can be mapped by the quantum sizes

```
+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| Quantum Range | Packet Size | Max Intensity |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|  8            |  32 bits    |        255    |
| 16            |  64 bits    |      25535    |
| 32            | 128 bits    | 4294967295    |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Ha! I figured it might have to do w/ the quantum range based off this [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184244/applying-a-logo-to-a-tshirt-using-php-imagick) but wasn't able to make the leap for the `pow(2, Q)` bit, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer above I'll just post my own solution in case it might benefit others. Essentially just massaging the `Imagick` class a bit to make it more sane for a human user. The good news is, it doesn't violate the syntax of the existing `paintTransparentImage` function since the `fuzz` parameter is already listed as a float (it does change the semantics though). This tweak just makes it resemble the cli interface where you can pass a percentage (although here you will pass `.1` instead of `10` to indicate 10%).

```
class SaneImagick extends Imagick
{
    public function paintTransparentImage($target, $alpha, $fuzz)
    {
        $iQuantumDepth = pow(2, $this->getQuantumDepth()['quantumDepthLong']);
        return parent::paintTransparentImage($target, $alpha, $fuzz * $iQuantumDepth);
    }
}
```